# How to Update Bitbucket Build Status from Azure Pipeline with Custom Message and Values?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket, pipeline

How can I update the build status from Azure Pipeline to Bitbucket with a custom message and custom values? I've tried below API, but they didn't update the build status as expected. My goal is to see the build status reflected in commits and pull requests in Bitbucket.

`curl -X POST -is -u <USER_NAME>:<APP_PASSWORD> \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<USER_NAME>/<REPOSITORY_SLUG>/commit/<COMMIT>/statuses/build \ -d '{ "state": "SUCCESSFUL", "name": "Build key - description", "url": "https://<AZURE_URL_REFERENCE>", "description": "A general description" }'`

What Do I Need to Do to Update Bitbucket Build Status from Azure Pipeline with Custom Message and Values

Answer (score 0):

To address my issue, I added the 'key' as 'my-build' in the CURL command and successfully triggered a 'SUCCESSFUL' build status update for the 'Build key - description' with a general description. The update was made to the Bitbucket repository using the provided API call, as shown in the command below:

`curl -X POST -is -u <USER_NAME>:<APP_PASSWORD> \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<USER_NAME>/<REPOSITORY_SLUG>/commit/<COMMIT>/statuses/build \ -d '{ "key": "my-build", "state": "SUCCESSFUL", "name": "Build key - description", "url": "https://<AZURE_URL_REFERENCE>", "description": "A general description" }'`